# Names of nerves in hands, shins and face

Tags: human-anatomy, cranial-nerves, peripheral-nervous-system

I am looking for the names of the nerves in 3 specific locations of the human body:

- The nerve running along the "top" (opposite side of the palm) portion of the thumb, from knuckle to fingernail (see 1st picture below); and
- The nerve running along the anterior tibia (also see 1st picture below); and
- The nerve(s) of the face running along the eyebrows and outer edges of the eye sockets (see 2nd picture below)

After looking [here](https://bedahunmuh.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/facial-nerve-schema.jpg?w=800), [here](http://www.innerbody.com/image/nerv01.html) and [here](http://www.bartleby.com/107/illus788.html), the best I could muster was:

- The **median nerve** is the nerve that carries sensory signals from the top of my thumb; and
- The **superficial peroneal nerve** is the nerve that carries sensory signals from my anterior tibia

But in every diagram of the face's nerves, there are simply too many for the article/blog/diagram to enumerate, and I can't discern which specific nerve or nerves runs outside of the eyes and across the brows.

Any ideas? Here are the pics to solidify the specific areas I'm looking for:

[image]

[image]

Please note: this is not homework! And although it may be considered by some to be a rudimentary question, I have actively tried to research this myself and have come up short. Below, I explain all the failed methods I attempted to figure this out on my own. So all this to say: if you do down/closevote this, please don't do it because you think it's homework or because you think it shows a lack of research!

Comment: I have made some structural edits by placing the this-is-not-homework comment below the question. Hope that's fine. You can roll back easily if you don't like it. I edited the tags. This is definitely unrelated to the central nervous system.

Comment: http://classes.kumc.edu/sah/resources/handkines/nerves/nerve.htm

Comment: https://home.comcast.net/~wnor/antlegdorsalfoot.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the Trigeminal nerve, the largest nerve in the face. Here it is with its branches.

[image]

It is both afferent and efferent.

[image]

[Afferent and efferent components of the facial nerve in the bullfrog (Rana catesbeiana)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/310889)
[Cranial Nerves Illustrated: Figure V-4 General sensory component of the trigeminal nerve, ophthalmic (V1) division.
General sensory afferent (blue-green)](http://www.bmc.med.utoronto.ca/cranialnerves/?page_id=26)